# Query to filter contacts with given tags while having many to many relation between entities

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing a simple contact management app. In my domain mode i have many to many relation between contacts and tags. Now inside my mvc I am in need to ask take user selected tags and return all the contacts that have any of its tags match with user supplied tags.

For example if contact najam has 3 tags - "author", "blogger", "subscriber" and admin chooses "author" and "subscriber" for search than najam should be in results.

```
public class Tag {

    public Tag()
    {
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public int TagID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public Contact()
    {
        isNewsletterSubscriber = true;
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public string CellPhone { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool isNewsletterSubscriber { get; set; }
    public string Twitter { get; set; }
    public string Facebook { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

I have been playing with LinqPad linq Expression but couldn't figure out a solution for this. I tried using contains and ant inside where clause.

Comment: Show us what you've tried with linq expressions that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following contacts:

```
var contacts = new List<Contact>()
{
    new Contact(){ 
        FirstName = "Najam", 
        Tags = new Collection<Tag>()
        {
            new Tag(){ Name = "author" },
            new Tag(){ Name = "blogger" },  
            new Tag(){ Name = "subscriber" }
        }
    },
    new Contact(){ 
        FirstName = "Mick", 
        Tags = new Collection<Tag>()
        {
            new Tag(){ Name = "author" },
        }
    },
        new Contact(){ 
        FirstName = "Ryan", 
        Tags = new Collection<Tag>()
        {
            new Tag(){ Name = "subscriber" }
        }
    },
};
```

And the following search tags:

```
var tagsToSearch = new Collection<Tag>()
{
    new Tag() {Name = "author"},
    new Tag() {Name = "blogger"}
};
```

Yo can do the following LINQ query to search the list of contacts that have the tags in question:

```
 var searchResults = contacts.Where(c => c.Tags.Any(t=> tagsToSearch.Any(tts=>tts.Name == t.Name)));
```

If you implement `IEquatable<Tag>` on your Tag class you can also do:

```
var searchResults = contacts.Where(c => c.Tags.Any(tagsToSearch.Contains));
```